# How to Bulk update records in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have multiple fields in my database and I want to update all records on submit button, Please let me know how i can do it.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(default=None)
    type=models.CharField(default=None)
    father=models.CharField(default=None)
    model1=models.Foreignkey(Category, related_name='cat_product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def display_data(request, id):
    test_display = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'test_display': test_display
    }
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

here is my `page.html` file...

```
<form method="POST" action={% url 'back:formupdate' %}
{% csrf_token %}
{% for test in test_display %}
<p>{{  test.name  }}</p>
<p>{{  test.type  }}</p>
<p>{{  test.phone  }}</p>
<p><input type="text" name="father" value="{{test.father}}"></p>
<p>{{  test.model1 }}</p>
<button class='btn btn-success'>Update Record</button>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to update `father` record in all fields, I want to update `bulk records`...
I want to update this record in all my database entries....

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

Answer (score 0):

Typically, using the model instance from the database and calling the save method will update that instance, you can therefore do this for `n` number of operations too.

```
for idVal in range(<fieldEntries>):
    t = Product.objects.get(id=idVal)
    t.father= <anyValue> # change field
    t.save() # this will update only
```

However, it's inefficient for handling large volumes of records. In this case use - [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

In short, you should be able to use:

```
ModelClass.objects.filter(name='bar').update(name="foo")
```

Comment: could you please write complete code with update in `views.py` file..